# Response from Solr should be returned in JSON in RESTful API in JAX-RS?

Tags: rest

I want to send response as 
@Produces("application/json") in RESTful API.
If I am trying to return QueryResponse its showing 404 error.

```
@GET
@Path("/search/json")
@Produces("application/json")
public QueryResponse listSearchJson()throws SolrServerException{
QueryResponse qr=myFunction.responseFromSolr();
return qr;
```

where responseFromSolr() returns response in QueryResponse.

If I use @Produces("text/plain")
and return String its showing but not in JSON format,all the data value pair is showing without double quotes.

If I am trying to see the response in browser,its showing correct. I have added &wt=json use returns the response in JSON.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? I have the same issue.